# Loading classes with inheritance from package

Tags: python

Following structure:

```
app.py
  /package
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
```

"foo.py" and "bar.py" contains both classes "Foo" and "Bar". Class "Foo" inherits from class "Bar". We have following code in the files...

"app.py":

```
from package import Foo

print Foo()
```

"__init__.py":

```
from foo import Foo
from bar import Bar
```

"foo.py":

```
class Foo(Bar):
    pass
```

"bar.py":

```
class Bar:
    pass
```

If I create an instance from "Foo" I became an name error "name 'Bar' is not defined". What I have to do to make it work? I am using Python 2.6.6 if it matters...

.oO(I'm new to Python)

Comment: you'll have to show real code, there isn't enough to go on here.

Comment: Put `from bar import Bar` to *foo.py*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the line

```
from bar import Bar
```

in the file `foo.py` (*not* just in `__init.py__`).

Comment: Don't use implicit relative imports. You could: `from package import Bar` (relies on the import in `__init__.py`) or `from package.bar import Bar` or `from .bar import Bar`.